# How to conditionally format a SUBSET of text in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Want to color specific text within a cell of Google Sheets, for example:

```
The {Login Page} shall contain a [Login Button]
```

I want {Login Page} to be red while [Login Button] is orange.

Would like to achieve this using conditional formatting (unless you can convince me that Google Sheets' scripts are simple and easy to learn).

Is this possible with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after this then it's **NOT** possible:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

---

You can do this only manually. There is no way to pull this off automatically in Google Sheets with formulas, conditional rules nor even with a script. Multicolor text is not supported to be achieved other than setting it up manually on non-formula output.

Also transferring (see image 1) multiple individual colors from in-one-cell to another cell is not possible at this current version of the Google Sheets (nor at any previous versions).

The next and last thing you can do is overlay it with a Drawing or Image like: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130191/186471**

Comment: That is unfortunate, but thank you for the response.